# Wrapper with onclick takes priority over child with href

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a wrapper box which has an onclick event to make the whole box cickable to go to a different page, something like this:

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://dom.com/page1/'">
    <p>Title</p>
    <img alt='img' />
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="http://dom.com/page2/">My link</a>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that the child link will never go to page2 because the parent onclick takes priority and wherever you click on the box you will always end up in page1.

Is there any way to solve this, I need to be able to go to page1 when clicking anywhere on the box but going to page2 when clicking on the link.

Answer (score 1):

The "onclick" handler is old-school. I'd recommend downloading and including [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your HTML, then using it like so:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
  jQuery( "div" ).click( function( e ){
    window.location='http://dom.com/page1/';
    e.preventDefault();
  };
} );
```

You probably don't need the e.preventDefault(); line, as you're changing the location of the browser before it executes.

Also, it's good practice to avoid applying click handlers to  tags. Perhaps you should use two  tags and CSS to properly position and layer to the two over-top each other.

Comment: I use jQuery alot and its always part of every project, however I dont get see how to get your snippet to work. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: ps. Instead of using a <div>, you should try an <a> with the CSS "display:block". Then, replace the inner <a> with <span> tags, and use CSS to format it accordingly. That'll get rid of the need for JavaScript altogether (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into event capturing and event bubbling. [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) is a nice article to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

One hack around it is to have anchor tag instead of `div` and make it block level element:

```
<a href="http://dom.com/page1/" style="display: block; text-decoration: none;">
   <p>Title</p>
   <img alt='img' />
   ...
</a>
```

This will also work when JS is disabled and the only downside is that it's not really elegant.

Comment: The problem with using an anchor as wrapper is that it will then not validate. A better option must be available.

Comment: @Mark nobody is forcing you to use strict HTML I believe that in "loose" mode it will validate fine.